# Why does com.netflix.spectator.api.Counter produes "normalized" values?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, metrics, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to use [Spectator](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR4/#netflix-metrics) for counting. The usage is as follows:

```
@Autowired
private Registry registry;
```

and than call:

```
registry.counter("ping").count();
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/metrics` I see:

```
"ping(type=NORMALIZED)":0.05
```

Why does this happens? How do I configure Spectator for counting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spectator parlance, a `Counter` is used to measure the rate at which some event is occurring (i.e. is always normalized over some time domain). A more detailed explanation is available [here](http://netflix.github.io/spectator/en/latest/intro/counter/). This normalization is performed by the metrics publisher before the metric is shipped to metrics server (e.g. Atlas is set to publish on a fixed time interval, and so normalizes over that time window). Since for a counter the *rate* is what is important, the discrete counter events within a time window do not need to be preserved.

If you instead just want to count the total number of occurrences of something across *all time*, you should use a `Gauge` (see [explanation](http://netflix.github.io/spectator/en/latest/intro/gauge/)) instead. I would caution you, however, that for a long running service counting total occurrences of some event occurring may eventually overflow. Typically, Gauges are used to count things that have a natural upper bound (and are not necessarily monotonically increasing), such as the total number of elements in a cache, or number of running threads.